# SearchView.onQueryTextListener does not work in Fragment (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

the problem that I present is with respect to the event `onQueryTextListener`, I declare it as it used it in java previously, but it does not show the log when I submit a text or when I change the text.

This is the code of my fragment:

**Fragment_producto.kt**

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val vG = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_producto, container, false)
    vG.recycler_producto.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    vG.recycler_producto.hasFixedSize()
    vG.recycler_producto.adapter = Producto_Adapter(activity,this)

    vG.fab_scan.onClick {
        IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this@Fragment_producto).initiateScan()
    }

    adapter = vG.recycler_producto.adapter as Producto_Adapter

    metodos.attachSwipeCheck(vG.recycler_producto)
    metodos.attachSwipeWrong(vG.recycler_producto)

    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    return vG
}    

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    Log.i(TAG,"Llego a create optionsmenu")
    activity.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_producto,menu)
    /*val menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
    val search = menuItem.actionView as SearchView
    searching(search)*/
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}

override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu) {
    val menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
    val search = menuItem.actionView as SearchView
    searching(search)
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
}

private fun searching(search: SearchView){
    search.onQueryTextListener {object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            Log.i(TAG,"Llego al querysubmit")
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
            Log.i(TAG,"Llego al querytextchange")
            return true
        }
    }}
}
```

Help me please.

Thanks

Comment: can you try with regular braces instead of curly braces for `search.onQueryTextListener`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try changing your `searching` method to this:

```
private fun searching(search: SearchView) {
    search.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            Log.i(TAG,"Llego al querysubmit")
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
            Log.i(TAG,"Llego al querytextchange")
            return true
        }
    })
}
```

I haven't tested it but your brackets seem iffy. I think there should be `()` instead of `{}`

The method you are using `onQueryTextListener` (as compared to `setOnQueryTextListener` in my code above) does not compile for me. Do you use any extension methods there? Maybe that method takes a function `String->()` as an argument, so when you put the `OnQueryTextListener` in the `{}` you are just giving a lambda to the method as an argument that creates an object but never uses it.

Comment: Yep, I use `coroutine` to create the event of the `searchView`, your code works for me, but I still have the doubt because it does not result with `onQueryTextListener`, use other `coroutine` for actions on the buttons for example, with those curly braces, and if it works, I do not understand why this time it does not work

Answer (score 1):

I had to also implement the listener for it to compile properly:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
        android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            //
            return false
        }
        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            //
            return false
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your xml code;

if your using androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView you should use that object

```
 setOnQueryTextListener(object : androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
                    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                        return false
                    }

                    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                        return true
                    }
                })
```

or change your searchView to standard one.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had the same problem, my onQueryTextChange was not triggered... And after some search i found out that i was using androidx so i have to change my menu from : `app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"` to `app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"`
Also make sur that in your activity or fragment you importe the right SearchView: `import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` and not the android widget.

Finally if you want to add Focus listener, to know when the searchview is in use or not do this :

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener ( object : View.OnFocusChangeListener{
                override fun onFocusChange(p0: View?, p1: Boolean) {
                    println("focus cahanged")
                    println(p1)
                }

            })
```

This return true is the searchview in focus and false if not.